# Vorto-Dashboard not showing device data

Tags: node.js, npm, oauth2client, bosch-iot-suite, eclipse-vorto

I am trying to run Vorto-dashboard on my Raspberry pi to show temperature sensor data.
I created an info model, integrated the device, sent the data with a python script.

I managed to run the dashboard as mentioned in the tutorials but the problem is the dashboard in showing black screen without any output.

the credentials have been passed using environmental variables in .bashrc as it was mentioned to me that passing them using ***config.json*** file has been omitted as below

```
export BOSCH_CLIENT_ID=""
export BOSCH_CLIENT_SECRET=""
export BOSCH_SCOPE=""
export REACT_APP_DEVICE_REFRESH_MS=10000
```

I can see the sensor data using the Bosch IoT Swagger UI "Bosch Things API" but I can't see anything in the dashboard.
I tried running the dashboard using the below commands and the output is always the same

```
vorto-dashboard
npm start
node index.json
```

The terminal output I am getting is below

> App running on port 8080 Backend queried with filterString...  Backend
>
> queried with filterString... location Could not get device img, using
>
> default vorto logo... StatusCodeError: 401 - "" Could not get device img, using default vorto logo... StatusCodeError: 401 - ""
>
> => Successfully pulled 2 things. Found 2 things for filter
>
> => Successfully pulled 2 things. Found 2 things for filter location Backend queried with filterString...
>
> => Successfully pulled 2 things. Found 2 things for filter  Backend queried with filterString...
>
> => Successfully pulled 2 things. Found 2 things for filter

I would like to ask if anyone faced a similar problem or if I done anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reproduce the described behavior of your dashboard, I am certain that the appearing error does not lie in the configuration/connection via **config.json** or environment variables. As the logs state, the node application("backend") is successfully connected and able to pull from the Bosch Things API. Therefore, it seems as if the structure in your provided sensor data is causing some kind of parsing bug in the react front-end of the dashboard.

Can you provide either the console output of your browser, or an example of the sensor data you are trying to show for me to have a closer look at it? Are you working with any topology structure with references between the provided things? Best regards